# Flask authentication (login page)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I'm trying to create a login page using flask and when they enter their correct credentials they will pass, but even when they enter a wrong password and username they will pass anyway!

**my form index.html**

```
<form method="post" action="/" role="login">
                <h3>ADMIN LOGIN</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" />
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login Now</button>

                <a href="#">Reset password</a>
            </form>
```

My **identityFace.py** as my main

```
    from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, redirect, g, url_for
import os
import model  as dbHandler

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'development key'

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        # dbHandler.insertUser(username, password)
        users = dbHandler.retrieveUsers()
        return render_template('home.html', users=users)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and my **model.py** is

```
import sqlite3 as sql

def retrieveUsers():
    con = sql.connect("ExamsFaceId.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT username, password FROM users")
    users = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()

    return users
```

It doesn't return an error.

Comment: You aren't actually checking if the entered values exist in the database... Also, poor idea to store plaintext passwords

Answer (score 0):

All you did want query for all the users in the database. Nowhere did you verify the entered information

Try implementing your own `userExists(username, password)` function against the database.

For example,

```
'SELECT username WHERE username=%s AND password=%s'
```

Then `return cur.rowcount > 0`

Back in Flask, check `if not db.userExists(username, password)`, then `redirect()` back to login.

Alternatively, I think you should really just be using [Flask-Admin + Flask-Security plugins](https://github.com/flask-admin/Flask-Admin/tree/master/examples/auth) because it'll give you this and fix your plain-text password problem.